# What factors affect the star rating at the end of a level?

Tags: angry-birds-epic

It appears that the amount of health that the birds have left is one factor, but what else affects the number of stars you earn when a level is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of stars you get at the end of the level is purely based on how many points you get.  (Each level though seems to have a slightly different point threshold for # of stars depending on how many enemies and how many birds you have).

Here is how I think the points are calculated based on my playing:

- Each fully healthy bird at the end of the fight is worth 10000 points.
- The minimum amount of points for a bird at the end of the fight is 5000 points.  Dead birds earn no points.
- Each pig has a certain point value, as the rounds go by their point value decreases.
- I have noticed that enemies killed during their turn either via DoTs or damage reflection gives the same points as if they were killed on your turn, so it seems that the point score decreases for every complete round (your turn + pigs' turn).

Thus, if you kill everything on round 1 while taking no damage, you will have the maximum possible score for that level.

Also, its worth it to heal up your birds before ending a fight (if the situation allows) to earn more points for the fight.